# Unicode with svn command line

Tags: svn, unicode, cmd, tortoisesvn, addition

I have a little problem using svn command line. I have files which names are written on Cyrillic. When I try to add them in repository through svn command line, I get error.

command: **svn add тест.txt**
error: svn: warning: W155010: 'C:\SomeFolder\**oano.txt**' not found
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation

-> I tried using --encoding, but I can't use it with add.
-> I tried changing cmd code page with chcp 65001 (UTF8) and the font (Lucida), the same error. 
-> I tried using CreateProcessW, still the same error. 
-> I tried to copy the file using cmd (copy тест.txt тест1.txt) and the file is copied without a problem (currently is the default code page 866).

As I can see, the filename can't be read properly, so the svn can't find the file. And I don't know how to fix it.

I found similar question here: [How to manipulate unicode-named files with subversion in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228046/how-to-manipulate-unicode-named-files-with-subversion-in-windows)
but I don't understand how the problem is fixed :/