# What does "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" actually do?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, windows-10

In some Windows 10 builds (insiders starting April 2018 and also "normal" 1903) there is a new option called "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support".

You can see this option by going to Settings and then:
All Settings -> Time & Language -> Language -> "Administrative Language Settings"

This is what it looks like:

[image]

When this checkbox is checked I observe some irregularities (below) and **I would like to know what exactly this checkbox does and why the below happens**.

Create a brand new Windows Forms application in your Visual Studio 2019. On the main form specify the `Paint` even handler as follows:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Font buttonFont = new Font("Webdings", 9.25f);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "0r", buttonFont, new Point(), Color.Black);
}
```

Run the program, here is what you will see if the checkbox is NOT checked:

[image]

However, if you check the checkbox (and reboot as asked) this changes to:

[image]

You can look up  [Webdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdings) font on Wikipedia. According to character table given, the codes for these two characters are `"\U0001F5D5\U0001F5D9"`. If I use them instead of `"0r"` it works *with* the checkbox checked but *without* the checkbox checked it now looks like this:

[image]

I would like to find a solution that *always* works that is regardless whether the box checked or unchecked.

Can this be done?

Comment: The system locale determines the ANSI and OEM codepages. The checkbox  forces them to UTF-8 (codepage 65001). Apparently this has a secondary effect that causes `DrawText` to not render "0r" using the selected font. I'd guess it's because symbol fonts such as Webdings and Wingding don't claim any Unicode ranges or legacy codepages in the font's OS/2 table. Instead they map codes to arbitrary glyphs. Continuing to guess, maybe `"\U0001F5D5\U0001F5D9"` will work if you select a regular font. Apparently font fallback can find the needed font(s).

Comment: maybe useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/international-fonts-in-windows-forms-and-controls

Comment: Other than the first two sentences, I was just speculating. You're closer to the problem and its solution than I am. I'd prefer for you to answer this yourself if you don't mind.

Comment: What encoding is your source code in? Changing the Windows setting will change CP_ACP which will change the interpretation of characters in text files that do not have an explicit encoding (via BOM). You source appears to contain extended characters. In source code I recommend using unicode escape codes in string literals for any characters that aren't ASCII, otherwise you are depending on ambient settings which may vary (are varying in this scenario).

Comment: @PaulDempsey all information to reproduce it is given in the question. No special encoding changes were made that were not mentioned in the OP. Adittionally, my source does not appear to contain extended characters other than unicode escape codes in string literals, which are marked as such in the OP.

Comment: You could take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows

Answer (score 16):

You can see it in ProcMon.
It seems to set the `REG_SZ` values `ACP`, `MACCP`, and `OEMCP` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage`
 to `65001`.

I'm not entirely sure but it **might** be related to the variable `gAnsiCodePage` in `KernelBase.dll`, which `GetACP` reads. If you *really* want to, you *might* be able to change it dynamically for your program regardless of the system setting by dynamically disassembling `GetACP` to find the instruction sequence that reads `gAnsiCodePage` and obtaining a pointer to it, then updating the variable directly.

(Actually, I [see references to an undocumented function named `SetCPGlobal`](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20040172601A1/en) that would've done the job, but I can't find that function on my system. Not sure if it still exists.)

Comment: Thank you, indeed the values 'ACPT', 'MACCP' and 'OEMCP' change to 65001 if UTF-8 is ticked. How did you find out in the first place that these are the registry-values that are modified by the UTF-8 checkbox?

Comment: @JoakimThorén: You can see it in [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)?

Answer (score 9):

Please look at this question to see what it solves when it is enabled: [How to save to file non-ascii output of program in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062063/how-to-save-to-file-non-ascii-output-of-program-in-powershell)

Also I found explanation written by Ghisler helpful ([source](https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=371547#p371547)):

> If you check this option, Windows will use codepage 65001 (Unicode
> UTF-8) instead of the local codepage like 1252 (Western Latin1) for
> all plain text files. The advantage is that text files created in e.g.
> Russian locale can also be read in other locale like Western or
> Central Europe. The downside is that ANSI-Only programs (most older
> programs) will show garbage instead of accented characters.

---

I leave here two ways to enable it, I think they will be helpful for many users:

1. Win+R -> `intl.cpl`
2. `Administrative` tab
3. Click the `Change system locale` button.
4. Enable `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`
5. Reboot

or alternatively via `reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"ACP"="65001"
"OEMCP"="65001"
"MACCP"="65001"
```

Comment: Nice; also worth mentioning that a reboot is required (if you do it via Control Panel, you'll be prompted). Note that the setting applies to both the _OEM_ code page (as used in _console_ applications; e.g. `437` ([CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) on US-English systems) and the _ANSI_ code page (as used in GUI-subsystem applications; e.g., `1252` ([Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)). Using this still-in-beta setting has far-reaching consequences, so it may not be for everyone - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

Answer (score 6):

Most Windows C APIs come in two different variants:

- "A" variant that uses 8-bit strings with whatever the systems configured encoding is.  This varies depending on the configured country/language. 
  (Microsoft calls the configured encoding the "ANSI Code Page", but it's not really anything to do with ANSI).
- "W" variant that uses 16-bit strings in a fixed almost-UTF-16 encoding.  (The "almost" is because "unpaired surrogates" are allowed; if you don't know what those are then don't worry about them).

The official Microsoft advice is not to use the "A" versions, but to ensure your code always use uses the "W" variants.  That way you're supposed to get consistent behaviour no matter what the user's country/language is configured as.

However, it looks like that checkbox is doing more than one thing.  It's clear it's supposed to change the "ANSI Code Page" to 65001, which means UTF-8.  It looks like it's also changing font rendering to be more Unicody.

I suggest you detect if [GetACP()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getacp) == [65001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers), then draw the Unicode version of your strings, otherwise draw the old "0r" version.  I'm not sure how you do that from .NET...

Comment: The "A" variant worked with ANSI C, C89 and C90. The "W" variant did NOT work with ANSI C, and was not compatible with portable ('ANSI') C until the standards of C95 were widely adopted.

Comment: @david: I'm talking about the Windows-specific APIs such as CreateFileA / CreateFileW.  They are completely independent of what language you're using, whether that's some revision of C, or C++, or Pascal, or whatever.  You're talking about the changes Microsoft proposed to the official C specification to add better wide-char support, which are a different thing (and are part of the C runtime, not the core OS API).

Comment: And I was commenting on your assertion that the ANSI API (available for use with ANSI c) had nothing to do with ANSI.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages explains the origin of the "A" suffix: "Windows code pages, commonly called "ANSI code pages", are [encodings] ... Originally, Windows code page 1252, the code page commonly used for English and other Western European languages, was based on an American National Standards Institute (ANSI) draft. ... but Windows code page 1252 was implemented before the standard became final, and is not exactly the same ...  The "A" version handles text based on Windows code pages".

Comment: I.e. the suffix is "A" because Windows supported a bunch of 8-bit encodings, the one commonly used by Microsoft was based on an ANSI draft code page, but most of the others had nothing to do with ANSI.  So the entire encoding mechanism got wrongly called "ANSI Code Page" by western programmers, and the name stuck.

It's nothing to do with ANSI C.

Comment: The Windows double byte encodings were implemented at a time that ANSI C was an important name for an important coding standard that indicated a specific and important api -- the ANSI C api.  "ANSI C" is the "ANSI" in the Windows ANSI api -- the api specified for ANSI C,

Comment: Muddy waters... quoting April 2022 Windows App Desktop Design, "Until recently, Windows has emphasized "Unicode" -W variants over -A APIs. However, recent releases have used the ANSI code page and -A APIs as a means to introduce UTF-8 support to apps. If the ANSI code page is configured for UTF-8, -A APIs typically operate in UTF-8. This model has the benefit of supporting existing code built with -A APIs without any code changes."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page

Answer (score 1):

On my windows, When I checked the `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`.
The following regedit values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage` changed.

```
ACP: 936 -> 65001
MACCP: 10008 -> 65001
OEMCP : 936 -> 65001
```

If I do not checked, then the visual studio compilation failed with `Exception: Bad UTF-8 encoding (U+FFFD; REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) found while decoding string: ...`, If I checked, then the compilation successed, but the os is full with unreadable code.