# Win32 programming and char type as UTF-8

Tags: winapi, utf-8

Many Operating Systems such as Linux and FreeBSD already treats `char` type as UTF-8, but Windows still treats it as [old MBCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/cpp/text/unicode-and-mbcs?view=vs-2019). With MBCS, we cannot handle a string with more than three non-alphabet characters such as "안녕你好こんにちはhello".

Is there any way of making my Windows program treat `char` type as UTF-8 instead of old MBCS? For example, [CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) gets file name string of `char*` as UTF-8, not MBCS. I guess there may be an way of doing it by calling a Win32 function or setting a value in [Manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/manifests).

Comment: Use UTF16 on Windows

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 ([build 17035](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8) and later) supports setting the active codepage of the system locale to UTF-8 ("[Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419639/what-does-beta-use-unicode-utf-8-for-worldwide-language-support-actually-do)"). If you cannot rely on a user configuring this on machines where your application will run then you have to use the old technique; `MultiByteToWideChar` and `CreateFileW`.