# How many Windows users have UTF-8 set as the code page?

Tags: windows, winapi, utf-8, codepages

In my understanding, the use of Windows filesystem functions accepting bytes (those with an `A` suffix) is discouraged (I didn’t find an official deprecation notice, but for example [Python](https://bugs.python.org/issue13374) deprecated their use).

On Unix-derived systems, file names are stored as bytes.  The encoding isn’t defined, but many systems are configured to interpret file names as UTF-8.

Since recently, it seems to be possible on Windows to set the code page to UTF-8.  Is it possible to estimate how many Windows users have that code page set?  Does it make sense to use the bytes-accepting filesystem API on Windows similar to how the POSIX API is used on Unix-derived systems (e.g. when porting some application from Linux to Windows)?

Comment: To the people who downvoted the question: I know that this question may be hard to ask in a good way. Can you make suggestions on how to improve the question?

Comment: It is impossible to answer the "how many" part. The other question is subjective. But the answer is surely that it does not make sense to use the 8 bit API. Whilst it might be convenient to use UTF8 everywhere Windows isn't ready for it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On Linux, it’s also impossible to estimate how many people are using UTF-8 as their system encoding. Still, nowadays most people seem to assume that everyone is using UTF-8. I deliberately didn’t ask how many people have that code page set. I asked whether it’s possible to do an estimatation at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So your answer was "no, it’s not possible to estimate how many" and "Windows is not ready for UTF-8 everywhere". Do you think it’s possible to restate my question in a way that this could be posted as an answer?

Comment: No. I don't think there is any way to ask this question without it attracting valid close votes.

Comment: One advice, forget everything you know from unix when trying windows programming. It's *way* different. Forget non-unicode *completely*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there is no convenience in using UTF-8 everywhere. In fact, UTF-8 is only used in a small part of programming.

Answer (score 4):

Only the newest versions of Windows 10 allows you to set the default codepage to UTF-8. This off-by-default feature is marked as Beta and has a couple of compatibility issues so I'm guessing the percentage is low.

The actual number is irrelevant because `CreateFileA` is just going to convert the string and call `CreateFileW` no matter what, and in the end, a UTF-16LE filename is going to be sent to the kernel. NTFS stores filename characters as 16-bit values and Windows interprets them as UTF-16LE strings (but without validating them AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Do you have a source for that it’s a beta feature? Are the compatibility issues documented somewhere?

Comment: The UI itself said BETA but I'm not sure when/if that has been removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56419639/3501 for at least one issue

Comment: One problem with setting the system locale to UTF-8 (codepage 65001) is that the system OEM codepage is used as the default for the console (conhost.exe). Setting the console's input codepage to UTF-8 limits reading input via `ReadFile` or `ReadConsoleA` to 7-bit ASCII since internally it doesn't support encoding to a multibyte encoding, and UTF-8 is 2-4 bytes per non-ASCII code point. It calls `WideCharToMultiByte` with a fixed internal buffer that assumes 1 byte per code point (or 2 bytes per code point for DBCS codepages). Each non-ASCII character is replaced by null in the result.