# How to save to file non-ascii output of program in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I want to run program in Powershell and write output to file with UTF-8 encoding.

However I can't write non-ascii characters properly.

I already read many similar questions on Stack overflow, but I still can't find answer.

I tried both `PowerShell 5.1.19041.1023` and `PowerShell Core 7.1.3`, they differently encode output file, but content is broken in the same way.

---

I tried simple programs in Python and Golang:

(Please assume that I can't change source code of programs)

### Python

```
print('Hello ąćęłńóśźż world')
```

**Results**:

`python hello.py`

```
Hello ąćęłńóśźż world
```

`python hello.py > file1.txt`

```
Hello ╣Šŕ│˝ˇťč┐ world
```

`python hello.py | out-file -encoding utf8 file2.ext`

```
Hello ╣Šŕ│˝ˇťč┐ world
```

On `cmd`:

`python hello.py > file3.txt`

```
Hello ���� world
```

---

### Golang

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello ąćęłńóśźż world\n")
}
```

**Results**:

`go run hello.go`:

```
Hello ąćęłńóśźż world
```

`go run hello.go > file4.txt`

```
Hello ─ů─ç─Ö┼é┼ä├│┼Ť┼║┼╝ world
```

`go run hello.go | out-file -encoding utf8 file5.txt`

```
Hello ─ů─ç─Ö┼é┼ä├│┼Ť┼║┼╝ world
```

On `cmd` it works ok:

`go run hello.go > file6.txt`

```
Hello ąćęłńóśźż world
```

Comment: Keep an eye on the code page your editor is using to write out your source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to enable `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support` as described in [What does "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419639/what-does-beta-use-unicode-utf-8-for-worldwide-language-support-actually-do)

**Note:** this solution may cause problems with legacy programs. Please read answer by **mklement0** and answer by **Quciksilver** for details and alternative solutions.

Also I found explanation written by Ghisler helpful ([source](https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=371547#p371547)):

> If you check this option, Windows will use codepage 65001 (Unicode
> UTF-8) instead of the local codepage like 1252 (Western Latin1) for
> all plain text files. The advantage is that text files created in e.g.
> Russian locale can also be read in other locale like Western or
> Central Europe. The downside is that ANSI-Only programs (most older
> programs) will show garbage instead of accented characters.

Also Powershell before version 7.1 [has a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/8896457) when this option is enabled. If you enable it , you may want to upgrade to version 7.1 or later.

I like this solution because it's enough to set it once and it's working. It brings consistent Unix-like UTF-8 behaviour to Windows. I hope I will not see any issues.

---

How to enable it:

1. Win+R → `intl.cpl`
2. `Administrative` tab
3. Click the `Change system locale` button
4. Enable `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`
5. Reboot

or alternatively via `reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"ACP"="65001"
"OEMCP"="65001"
"MACCP"="65001"
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set the [OutputEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=net-5.0) property of the console first.

In PowerShell, enter this line before running your programs:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8
```

You can then use `Out-File` with your encoding type:

```
py hello.py | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 file2.ext
go run hello.go | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 file5.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for golang program, but in my case it wasn't enough for python program.

Answer (score 3):

Note: These **character-encoding problems only plague PowerShell *on Windows***, in both editions. On Unix-like platforms, [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is consistently used.<sup>[1]</sup>

[Quicksilver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064432/45375) is fundamentally correct:

- **It is the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` that determines how PowerShell decodes text received *from* external programs**<sup>[2]</sup> - and note that it *invariably* interprets such output as text (strings).

  - `[Console]::OutputEncoding` by default reflects a console's active code page, which itself defaults to the system's active *OEM* code page, such as `437` ([CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) on US-English systems.
  - The standard `chcp` program also reports the active OEM code page, and while it can in principle also be used to *change* it for the active console (e.g., `chcp 65001`), this does *not* work from *inside* PowerShell, due to .NET caching the encodings.
- Therefore, **you may have to (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to match the actual character encoding used by a given external console program**:

  - **While many console programs respect the *active console code page* (in which case no workarounds are required), some do not**, typically in order to provide full Unicode support. Note that **you may not notice a problem until you *programmatically process* such a program's output** (meaning: capturing in a variable, sending through the pipeline to another command, redirection to a file), because such a program may detect the case when its stdout is directly connected to the console and may then selectively use full Unicode support *for display*.
  - Notable CLIs that do *not* respect the active console code page:

    - **Python** exhibits nonstandard behavior in that it uses the active *ANSI* code page by default, i.e. the code page normally only used by non-Unicode *GUI*-subsystem applications.

      - However, you can use `$env:PYTHONUTF8=1` *before* invoking Python scripts to instruct Python to use UTF-8 instead (which then applies to all Python calls made from the same process); in v3.7+, you can alternatively pass command-line option `-X utf8` (case-sensitive) as a per-call opt-in.
    - **Go** and also **Node.js** *invariably* use UTF-8 encoding.

The following snippet shows how to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` *temporarily* as needed:

```sh
# Save the original encoding.
$orig = [Console]::OutputEncoding

# Work with console programs that use UTF-8 encoding,
# such as Go and Node.js
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

# Piping to Write-Output is a dummy operation that forces
# decoding of the external program's output, so that encoding problems would show.
go run hello.go | Write-Output

# Work with console programs that use ANSI encoding, such as Python.
# As noted, the alternative is to configure Python to use UTF-8.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP))

python hello.py | Write-Output

# Restore the original encoding.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $orig
```

---

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68065963/45375) provides an **effective alternative, but it comes with *caveats***:

- Activating the `Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support` feature via Control Panel (or the equivalent registry settings) **changes the code pages *system-wide***, which affects not only all console windows and console applications, but also legacy (non-Unicode) *GUI*-subsystem applications, given that both the OEM and the ANSI code pages are being set.
- **Notable side effects** include:

  - ***Windows PowerShell*'s default behavior changes**, because it uses the ANSI code page both to read *source code* and as the default encoding for the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlets.

    - For instance, existing Windows PowerShell scripts that contain non-ASCII range characters such as `é` will then misbehave, *unless* they were saved as UTF-8 *with a BOM* (or as "Unicode", UTF-16LE, which always has a BOM).
    - By contrast, *PowerShell (Core) v6+* consistently uses (BOM-less) UTF-8 to begin with.
  - Old console applications may *break* with `65001` (UTF-8) as the active OEM code page, as they may not be able to handle the variable-length encoding aspect of UTF-8 (a single character can be encoded by up to 4 bytes).
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] The cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) v6+* edition](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) uses (BOM-less) UTF-8 consistently. While it is possible to configure Unix terminals and thereby console (terminal) applications to use a character encoding *other* than UTF-8, doing so is rare these days - UTF-8 is almost universally used.</sup>

<sup>[2] By contrast, it is the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)  that determines the encoding used for sending text *to* external programs, via the *pipeline*.</sup>