# UTF-8 characters not loading in properly

Tags: c++, utf-8, windows-console

I have a school project that requires me to load a text file that includes UTF-8 characters like `"ł,ą,ż,ź,ć,..."`, and then to do some editing on that text.

The problem is that, if I use `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)`, it loads the file correctly, but then if I try to use `cin` with `ł`, `ą`, etc then the characters disappear.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

string opfile(string name){
    string line;
    ifstream myfile (name);
    string tekst;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(myfile, line)) {
            tekst += line + "\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return tekst;
};

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    string file_name;
    cin >> file_name;
    cout << opfile(file_name);
    string cos;
    cin >> cos;
    cout << cos;
    return 0;
}
```

This is whats inside the text file

```
ŁŁŁŁŁŁŁŁĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄĄÓÓÓÓĆÓŹŻÓŹĆŹŻÓĆŻÓźćÓÓÓĆŹÓŻĆŻÓŹĆÓŚĄŚĄÓÓĄŚÓŚĄÓÓŚÓŚĄ
```

If I try to input this later, nothing is outputted.

I tried looking around, but everyone says the `SetConsoleOutputCP()` should work.

Comment: Clion , C++ 17 , Win 10, and I don't kno about the rest

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Clion compiler.  Does it have a **/utf-8** setting like the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler?

Comment: Ok Windows, but which compiler? MSVC, MinGW, clang?

Comment: There is no such thing like `UTF-8` characters. `UTF-8` is just encoding of Unicode characters. On Windows with polish locale console by default used code page 1252 which is one bye encoding which covers polish characters (Central Europe). Is your file/input realy `Utf-8` or Windows-1252?

Comment: Windows doesn't work very well with UTF-8, despite all the claims that it is supported "out of the box". It isn't.

Comment: It is Utf-8 in notepad

Comment: Having said that, your program works for me as is (both file loading and typing from the terminal) (Windows 11, MSVC 19.32.31332, Windows Terminal). I do use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419639/what-does-beta-use-unicode-utf-8-for-worldwide-language-support-actually-do). I think it might not work on Windows 10 (I remember struggling with UTF-8 console input on earlier Windows versions).

Comment: Yes the problem is that if i don't use SetConsoleOutputCP the file imports incorrectly but the cin saves the letters properly

Comment: What is your console's default codepage? If you use SetConsoleOutputCP, then it changes the *output* code page but not *input*.

Comment: What purpose do you use `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);` for? What happens without this instruction? What's the size of `cos` after you read in a UTF-8 text containing non-ASCII characters?